# Add css class to product attribute in Woo variations table plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I want to add the class="notranslate" only to the product attribute called "MARCAJE", the slug is "pa_marcaje". What do I am doing wrong??

Could you help me please??

This is the code:

```
   foreach ($available_variations as $variation) {

        $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation['variation_id'] );

        $this->td .= '<tr id="variations-table-row-' . $variation_product->get_id() . '" class="variations-table-row">';
        foreach($this->variationsTableData as $variationsTableDataKey => $variationsTableDataValue) {
            if($variationsTableDataKey == "at") {

                foreach ($variation_product->get_attributes() as $attr_name => $attr_value) {
                    // Get the correct variation values
                    if (strpos($attr_name, 'pa_') !== FALSE){ // variation is a pre-definted attribute
                        // $attr_name = substr($attr_name, 3);
                        $attr = get_term_by('slug', $attr_value, $attr_name);
                        $attr_value = $attr->name;

                        $attr_name = wc_attribute_label($attr_name);
                    } else {
                        $attr = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_product_attributes' ) );
                        $attr_name = $attr[0][$attr_name]['name'];
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    if($this->first) {
                        $this->th .= '<th id="variations-table-header-' . $variationsTableDataKey . '" class="variations-table-header">' . $attr_name . '</th>';
                        $this->columnCount++;
                    }
```

// This is the code I am writting

```
                    if($attr_name['name'] == "pa_marcaje"{
                        
                         $this->td .= '<td data-th="' . $attr_name . '" class="variations-table-value-' . $variationsTableDataKey . ' variations-table-value . notranslate">' . $attr_value . '</td>';
                        
                    }else{
```

// until here

```
                    $this->td .= '<td data-th="' . $attr_name . '" class="variations-table-value-' . $variationsTableDataKey . ' variations-table-value">' . $attr_value . '</td>';
                }
                }
                continue;
            }
```